# Daydream goes to standby when touched

Tags: standby, daydream

My Nexus 4 runs Android 4.4 and is set to use the standard "Clock" daydream while charging. It has no screen lock. This works fine so far.

Expected:
I would expect the screen to **wake up when I touch the daydreaming screen.**

Problem:
**Sometimes the screen turns off** when I touch it, rather than waking up.

Symptoms:
There might be a time element because this seems to happen when I have not touched the phone for many minutes, but it seems to work OK if it had only been daydreaming a few minutes. AC or USB charging does not seem to make any difference.

→ Why does the screen turn off instead of waking up, and how can I "fix" that?

Comment: This issue still occurs on Lollipop. However, I haven't tested if it's daydream-dependent or not.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem some time ago. It went away after i flashed kitkat as i didn'twant to wait for OTA update.

Try rebooting or write what you already did to try solve the problem

Comment: I reboot regularly; that doesn't seem to be a solution.

Comment: Nope, even after I flashed Lollipop, the problem still persists (or it became worse, actually)